# Clojure macros : Executing code inside macros

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to create a macro so that i can add the variable name inside the variable itself. I have this `Unit` record. Its `name` member stores the name of variable that would have been created.
i.e. like `(def a-variable (->Unit 1 1 "a-varible"))` 
but i donot want to pass the variable name myself.

And i think macros can come handy. :)

Here is the code :

```
(defrecord Unit 
    [value gradient name]
  Object
  (toString [_]
    (str name " : ")))


(defmacro create-unit1 [var-name & body]
  `(def ~var-name ~(concat body (list (name var-name)))))

(defmacro create-unit2 [var-name & body]
  `(def ~var-name (concat ~@body (list (name '~var-name)))))
```

But none of them is giving me write code :

```
neurals.core> (macroexpand '(create-unit1 a (->Unit 1.0 0.0)))
(def a ((->Unit 1.0 0.0) "a"))

neurals.core> (macroexpand '(create-unit2 a (->Unit 1.0 0.0)))
(def a (clojure.core/concat 
       (->Unit 1.0 0.0) (clojure.core/list 
                           (clojure.core/name (quote a)))))
neurals.core>
```

I wanted :

```
(def a (->Unit 1.0 0.0 (clojure.core/name (quote a))))
```

What is the right way to execute the `concat` inside the macro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your code by removing the `&` in `create-unit1`:

```
(defmacro create-unit1 [var-name body]
  `(def ~var-name ~(concat body (list (name var-name)))))

(macroexpand `(create-unit1 a (->Unit 1.0 1.0)))
;; => (def user/a (user/->Unit 1.0 1.0 "a"))
```

You could also add a little bit of syntactic sugar:

```
(defmacro create-unit1 [var-name body]
  `(def ~var-name (~@body ~(name var-name))))
```

Or, to keep all of that more idiomatic:

```
(defmacro defunit [sym value gradient]
  `(def ~sym (->Unit ~value ~gradient ~(name sym))))

(defunit a 1.0 1.0)
;; => #user.Unit{:value 1.0, :gradient 1.0, :name "a"}
```

Comment: oh.. `(~@body ~(name var-name))` is the way to concat it :).. cool